# Completely disable / deactivate USB in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: drivers, usb, usb-drive, removable-storage

I have some Ubuntu 10.04 based portable touchscreen computers at workplace and sometimes people would use USB data cable to charge their phones from the USB port.

Now I have usb storage access disabled ($sudo leafpad /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and entering blacklist usb_storage at the very end) but now we have a requirement to stop this USB-Phone-Charging also.

Any solutions to this bizarre requirement ???

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702216/controlling-a-usb-power-supply-on-off-with-linux) Stack Overflow QA help?

Comment: Put some glue in the ports (easy) or unsolder them (cleaner but requires disassembly of the device).

Comment: @AndréDaniel - that would be my last resort. for the time being looking forward to avoid going that way.